# MATLAB OpenGL Diagnosis

Tags: nvidia, graphics, opengl, matlab

## QUESTION

What can be done to troubleshoot the error message and restore MATLAB back to its original working condition?  A fresh install of MATLAB and Ubuntu 16.04 exhibited no symptoms.  After updates, an OpenGL symptom is present.

## ISSUE

R2018a on 16.04 initially did not exhibit the symptom, however updates  may have induced the Symptom:

> com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: X11GLXDrawableFactory - Could not
>   initialize shared resources for X11GraphicsDevice[type .x11,
>   connection :0, unitID 0, handle 0x0, owner false,
>   ResourceToolkitLock[obj 0x5d8aa476, isOwner false, [count 0, qsz 0, owner ]]]     at
>   jogamp.opengl.x11.glx.X11GLXDrawableFactory$SharedResourceImplementation.createSharedResource(X11GLXDrawableFactory.java:326)
>     at
>   jogamp.opengl.SharedResourceRunner.run(SharedResourceRunner.java:297)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrent(GLContextImpl.java:688)   at
>   jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrent(GLContextImpl.java:580)   at
>   jogamp.opengl.x11.glx.X11GLXDrawableFactory$SharedResourceImplementation.createSharedResource(X11GLXDrawableFactory.java:297)
>     ... 2 more

[Reconfiguring OpenGL per Mathworks guidance](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/342906-could-not-initialize-shared-resources-for-x11graphicsdevice) eliminates the error message, however, I suspect that it is suboptimal performance.

```
>> opengl('save','software')
```

BASH returns:

```
 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

> OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5

[image]

Any diagnostic questions are always appreciated: thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had issues with openGL. Matlab support team suggested I start matlab with the following command:

```
matlab -desktop -softwareopengl
```

By the way, I use Nvidia driver, not Xorg